# Obj-C, How can I use MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate as a parameter to a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to re-use in-app email functionality in my app, so i can call it from an info button on all of my views.

My problem is use `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` as a parameter to this function.

I think if I can get this to work, this will solve my other issues.

Comment: could you provide more details on what is the problem is?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to pass an `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` as a parameter to a method? Just declare the method something like this:

```
- (void)foo:(id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>)mf_delegate;
```

Comment: Yes, if you are calling this from a method of a UIViewController subclass that also conforms to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol, you could pass `self` as the parameter.

Comment: You don't *have* to pass `self`, you could pass any object that conforms to the appropriate protocol.